# Most modern way to prompt user to add web app to homescreen

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to prompt the user to add the web app to home screen on android and iphone. I tried this

https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen

but it doesn't seem to work. I tried this

```
    <script src="/js/plugin/addtohomescreen.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/addtohomescreen.css" />
    <script>
        addToHomescreen();
    </script>
```

but nothing happens. Is there a more modern way now using meta tags only? Or do we need js too? And how does it work if the user already has a shortcut on the homescreen, will it ask each time?

Thanks

Comment: what part of it doesn't work? do you get an error?

Comment: No error, but just I don't get any prompt.

Comment: I tried the demo on the github page, it is silent aswell. Maybe the implementation is broken. [Demo](http://lab.cubiq.org/addtohome/demos/simple/)

Comment: Do you know if there is a meta tag only way?

Comment: Maybe something like this `(function(){ addToHomeScreen(); })();` will work?

Comment: What device have you tested on?

Comment: Android phone, note 4 with chrome

Comment: Okay, I am not very familiar with android but I think the user will be prompted if you add `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`.

Comment: But iOS users will not be prompted unless you use something like  cubiq/add-to-homescreen